# why cpp allows to get a access to memory i haven't allocated?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

In cpp one can use an array declaration as
**typename array[size];**
or
**typename *array = new typename[size];**
Where array is of length 'size' and elements are indexed from '0' to 'size -1'
Here my question is am I allowed to access the elements beyond the index >= size.

So I wrote this little code to check it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //int *c;                    //for dynamic allocation
    int n;                       //length of the array c
    cin>>n;                      //getting the length
    //c = new int[n];            //for dynamic allocation
    int c[n];                    //for static allocation

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)       //getting the elements
        cin>>c[i];

    for(int i=0; i<n+10; i++)    //showing the elements, I have add up 10
        cout<<c[i]<<" ";         //with size to access the memory I haven't
                                 //allocated for
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is like this

```
2
1 2
1 2 2686612 1970422009 7081064 4199040 2686592 0 1 1970387429 1971087432 2686700
```

Shouldn't the program crashed but gives garbage values. And for both the allocation methods it gives the same result. It makes more bugs which are hard to detect. Is it related with the environment or the compiler I am using or anything else?

I was using codeblocks IDE having TDM-GCC 4.8.1 compiler on windows 8.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn´t allowed, but C++ doesn´t check this automatically like some other languages. The benefit are eg. faster programs, the downside what happens if the programmer makes an error. (Btw., maybe your current programs runs fine, but it is indeed an error and will often cause problems)

Comment: `int c[n];` actually allocates memory. Its a compiler extension of GCC.

Comment: You can use a tool like valgrind to detect such issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c++ compilers don't enforce this as there is no specification to do so.

When you access an element of an array there is no boundary check done. `c[i]` just gets translated to `c + i * sizeof(int)` and that's it. If that area of memory is not initialize you'll get garbage, but you could be getting other useful information it all depends on what is there.

Please note that depending on the OS and the c++ runtime you're running you can get different results, for instance on a linux box you'll probably be getting a `segmentation fault` and the program will crash.

Comment: Actually, accessing memory off the end of a valid allocation will not in most cases trigger a segmentation fault, as that results from an enforcement mechanism in the MMU/MPU which operates at page granularity.  If the allocation is in a valid page, you'd have to access beyond the end of that page, in a situation where there is no allocated page at the following address.  Incorrect operation is still likely, as the improper access may overwrite other important data or be overwritten by later valid access.  This is different from accessing an unallocated page, which the hardware can fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "undefined behavior" in the C++ standard.

Undefined behavior can mean any one of the following:

- The program crashes
- The program continues to run, but produces meaningless, garbage results
- The program continues to run, and automatically copies the entire contents of your hard drive, and posts it on Facebook
- The program continues to run, and automatically subscribes you to Publishers Clearinghouse Sweepstakes
- The program continues to run, but your computer catches fire and explodes
- The program continues to run, and makes your computer self-aware, which automatically links and networks with other self-aware networks, forming Skynet, and destroying the human race

Conclusion: do not run and access elements past the end of your arrays.

Comment: Yet another useless undefined behavior answer where the poster just make up things for fun without answering the question because "anything can happen" when undefined behavior is involved

Comment: What part of my answer was inaccurate?

Comment: I didn't say it was inaccurate, I said it was useless

Comment: So you're saying that my answer did absolutely nothing to explain what "undefined behavior" means?

Comment: Yes. Also, if you can explain any system that could cause `cout<<c[i]<<" ";` to post to Facebook given the OP's code I'd gladly drop the -1 :)

Comment: I already did. It's a fact that due to the way the C++ standard specifies "undefined behavior", this would be a valid outcome. Suppose, for example, someone has a self-masochistic streak, and a sense of humor; and rigs up a script to automatically flame himself on facebook, each time /var/log/messages logs a segfault in his code. And suppose there's a bug in the script that could result in the script ending up posting the entire contents of the hard drive instead. This code could then trigger a segfault, resulting in the entire contents of the hard drive going up on Facebook. Q.E.D.

Comment: Don't seem to be allowed to undo my vote. Still think it is a stretch but props for explaining how it could be possible